# How to create generic function in TS and TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

How to create generic function in TS and TypeORM?

I have a multiple functions like this:

```
    async getOrderName(id: number): Promise<string> {
        const order = await this.conn.getRepository(Order).findOne(id);
        return `${order.name}`;
    }
```

```
    async getServiceName(id: number): Promise<string> {
        const service = await this.conn.getRepository(Service).findOne(id);
        return `${service.name}`;
    }
```

and another ... another... another...

so, i need to create one generic function to use with the many entities

can somebody tell me how to create that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to take advantage of duck typing to generalize the functionality over `EntityTarget`s:

```js
interface NamedThing {
    name: string
}
async getName<Entity extends NamedThing>(id: number, target: EntityTarget<Entity>): Promise<string> {
    const named = await this.conn.getRepository<Entity>(target).findOne(id);
    return `${named && named.name}`;
}

// equivalent calls are now `getName(id, Order)`, `getName(id, Service)`, etc.
```

Comment: thanks, but from where i can get `EntityTarget`? This class is in typeORM?

Comment: instead of `EntityTarget` I use `ObjectType` and works perfectly, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend checking out      https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

You can pass in type T (and return type T) if you'd like.

```
  async getServiceName<T>(id: T): Promise<string> {
            const service = await this.conn.getRepository(Service).findOne(id);
            return `${service.name}`;
        }
```

Obviously you would have to overload findOne function to take any number of type T's. Or you could be super lazy and use any keyword in the lowest level.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to generalize over the ID types, but rather over the repositories that they fetch from. This unconstrained `id` also doesn't work, because the types of IDs to `findOne` are `string|number|Date|ObjectID`.

Comment: That's why I would overload it. Depending on the type would go to the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
const a = MyRepositoryName
```

and pass `a` as an argument to the function